# Why does System.out.println applied to this object print this phrase?

Tags: java, oop

I've got two classes, below. When I run the class TestSimple, it prints out "blueblueblue is blue repeated". That print statement is executed as `System.out.println(item)` which is an instance of the `Simple()` class. I've never seen an object print out as a phrase before, and I'm having a hard time pinning down why this is happening.

I see that there is a method in the `Simple` class called `toString` which should print this out when it is called, but I don't see that method called anywhere. What's going on here?

```
public class Simple {
     private String word; 
     private String phrase; 
     public Simple(int number, String w) {  
          word = w;     
          phrase = mystery(number, w);          
     }   
     private String mystery(int num, String s) {    
          String answer = "";   
          for (int k=0; k<num; k++) {       
               answer = answer + s;     
          }     
          return answer; 
     } 

     public String toString() {     
          return phrase + " is " + word + " repeated";
     }
}
```

And

```
public class TestSimple{
     public void print() {      
          Simple item = new Simple(3, "blue");      
          System.out.println(item);         
     }      

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestSimple().print();
    }
}
```

Comment: `toString()` is the method that will br invoked when an object is printed or otherwise implicitly converted to a string. That is the method's purpose.

Comment: When you print an object its toString is called implicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`System.out`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) is a `PrintStream`, [`PrintStream.println(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.Object-) (from the linked Javadoc) *calls at first `String.valueOf(x)` to get the printed object's string value* and [`String.valueOf(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-java.lang.Object-) returns *the value of `obj.toString()`*